# Hide certain table cells using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery,  if I click a row, I want to hide certain cells of that selected row and display back if I clicked again. I have looked everywhere but couldn't find any solution. Mostly hides complete row.
Here is the example table:

```js
$('.selectme').click(function() {
  $(this).has('td.hidene').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table1' border="1">
  <tr class='selectme'>
      <td class='donthide'>row 1, cell 1</td>
      <td class='hideme'>row 1, cell 2</td>
      <td class='hideme'>row 1, cell 3</td>
      <td class='hideme'>row 1, cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='donthideme'>
      <td class='dontletmehide'>row 2, cell 1</td>
      <td class='dontletmehide'>row 2, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well that won't really work, you'll be hard pressed to hide only certain cells. What you can do would be to hide the information in the cell. Or "hide" it by removing the right borders on those cells, potentially. How do you want it to look, be specific.

Comment: Hide the text of cell would also do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to call the `.has()` function on the current clicked tr `$(this)` when the `tr` has no class `.hideme`, Instead you should target the child elements using :

```
$('.hideme', this)
//Or
$(this).find('.hideme')
```

Then use `toggle()` function like :

```
$('.hideme', this).toggle();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.selectme').click(function() {
    $('.hideme', this).toggle();
    //Or
    //$(this).find('.hideme').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table1' border="1">
<tr class='selectme'>
    <td class='donthide'>row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td class='hideme'>row 1, cell 2</td>
    <td class='hideme'>row 1, cell 3</td>
    <td class='hideme'>row 1, cell 4</td>
</tr>
<tr class='donthideme'>
    <td class='dontletmehide'>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td class='dontletmehide'>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
```

**Snippet Hide just text :**

```js
$('.selectme').click(function() {
    $('.hideme', this).each(function(){
        if( $(this).text() == '' )
          $(this).text( $(this).data('text') );
        else{
          $(this).data('text', $(this).text());
          $(this).text('');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table1' border="1">
<tr class='selectme'>
    <td class='donthide'>row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td class='hideme'>row 1, cell 2</td>
    <td class='hideme'>row 1, cell 3</td>
    <td class='hideme'>row 1, cell 4</td>
</tr>
<tr class='donthideme'>
    <td class='dontletmehide'>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td class='dontletmehide'>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Zakaria. Your solution works like charm. just wondering if you can keep the structure of a table. I haven't mentioned it above and I'll give your answer green tick anyway.

Comment: You're welcome, please just describe more what you mean by _keep the structure of a table_

Comment: Below a guy had answered , if I click a cell text goes away but cell remains there. in that way structure of table remains.

Comment: Check plz the new snippet in my answer.

Comment: that's great :)

Answer (score 2):

you could like this `$(this).find('td[class="hideme"]').hide();`
if you need  a `toggle` effect use `toggle()` instead of `hide()`

```js
$('.selectme').click(function() {
     $(this).find('td[class="hideme"]').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table1' border="1">
  <tr class='selectme'>
    <td class='donthide'>row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td class='hideme'>row 1, cell 2</td>
    <td class='hideme'>row 1, cell 3</td>
    <td class='hideme'>row 1, cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='donthideme'>
    <td class='dontletmehide'>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td class='dontletmehide'>row 2, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing your Jquery wrong. You need to hide the clicked td and right now you are trying to hide the row that has a td.

Take a look at my example: [jsifddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pco2emjz/)

```
$('td').click(function() {
   $(this).hide();
});
```